# How to refresh list view by calling notifyOnDatasetChanged with in base adapter

Tags: android, listview, refresh, baseadapter

I am having the list view with buttons in my fragment class which was populated using the custom adapter.When the button which was present inside the list view was pressed i want to remove that item.Here i used the `notifyDataSetChanged` when ever the button clicks from my adapter class but it does not reflect any result.can any one tell me how to update the list view from adapter class
this is the code i had written inside my adapter class after clicking button

```
remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

My complete adapter code

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.lotus.com.androidmis.R;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.lotus.mis.modle.Complaints.Complaint;
import com.lotus.mis.modle.MyAppApplication;
import com.subtabs.complaints.Complaints_pending;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class Support_ComplainAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<Complaint> objects;
    ProgressDialog progressdialog;
    String UserID;
    MyAppApplication mApp;

    public Support_ComplainAdapter(Context context,int resource,List<Complaint> objects)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return  objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //  View POItemRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_poitem_listrow,parent,false);

        View PurchaseOrderRow = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_complaint_adapter,null);

        progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        if (position % 2 == 1) {
            PurchaseOrderRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);  
        } else {
            PurchaseOrderRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);  
        }
        mApp  = ((MyAppApplication)context.getApplicationContext());
        final Complaint TR = (Complaint)objects.get(position);

        final String RequestNO = TR.getTicketNo();
        final String reqID = TR.getComplaintID();

        Complaint Complaintlist = (Complaint) objects.get(position);

        //TextView txt_PONo = (TextView) PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.txt_PONo);
        //TextView txt_SuppName = (TextView) PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.txt_SuppName);
        TextView username = (TextView)PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.txt_complaint_empname);
        username.setText(mApp.getmGlobal_UserName());
        TextView userid = (TextView)PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.txt_complaint_userid);
        userid.setText(mApp.getmGlobal_UserID());
        TextView module_name  = (TextView)PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.txt_module_name);
        module_name.setText(Complaintlist.getText2());
        TextView Ref_no = (TextView)PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.txt_ref_no);
        Ref_no.setText(Complaintlist.getTicketNo());
        TextView created_by = (TextView)PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.txt_created_by_complaint);
        created_by.setText(Complaintlist.getCreatedBy());
        TextView created_Date= (TextView)PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.txt_created_date_complaint);
        created_Date.setText(Complaintlist.getCreatedDate());
        TextView complaint_sub = (TextView)PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.txt_complaint_sub);
        complaint_sub.setText(Complaintlist.getComplaintName());
        TextView complaint_body = (TextView)PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.txt_complaint_body);
        complaint_body.setText(Complaintlist.getText1());
        final Button chat_support = (Button)PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.btn_chat_support);
        chat_support.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

        final Button close_complaint = (Button)PurchaseOrderRow.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
        close_complaint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new set_updateSupport().execute("UpdateValues", "1011",
                        reqID, "", "", "", "",
                        "", "","","","");


            }
        });

return PurchaseOrderRow;
    }

    class set_updateSupport extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        private static final String NAME_SPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.106:99/Service.asmx";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressdialog.setMessage("Adding Sales Request");
            progressdialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String TempMethod = params[0];
            String Flag = params[1];
            String value1 = params[2];
            String value2 = params[3];
            String value3 = params[4];
            String value4 = params[5];
            String value5 = params[6];
            String value6 = params[7];
            String value7 = params[8];
            String value8 = params[9];
            String value9 = params[10];
            String value10 = params[11];

            try {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAME_SPACE, TempMethod);
                request.addProperty("Flag", Flag);
                request.addProperty("value1", value1);
                request.addProperty("value2", value2);
                request.addProperty("value3", value3);
                request.addProperty("value4", value4);
                request.addProperty("value5", value5);
                request.addProperty("value6", value6);
                request.addProperty("value7", value7);
                request.addProperty("value8", value8);
                request.addProperty("value9", value9);
                request.addProperty("value10", value10);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE Android_HttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                Android_HttpTransport.debug = true;
                Android_HttpTransport.call(NAME_SPACE + TempMethod, envelope);
                String responseXml = envelope.getResponse().toString();
                //  String responseXml = Android_HttpTransport.responseDump;
                Log.i("RITESH", "responseXml" + responseXml);
                return responseXml;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // super.onPostExecute(result);

            progressdialog.dismiss();

            if (result == null) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error while reading data",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (result.equals("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No record for Update",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (result.equals("1")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Complain/Support Close Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                notifyDataSetChanged();



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Not Updated result  " + result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: could you please explain your use case

Comment: i edited my question please see it

Comment: what changes you expect when calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: i posted my complete adapter code and i am calling that notifyOndatasetChanged in my async task after the result execution in async task

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the code that changes the "List objects" content.

You can try this:

```
objects.clear();  
objects.addAll(query(......)); 
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```